# How to robocopy folder between 2 servers in different domains?

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I have the following function to `robocopy` (mirror) files from `$sourcepath` to `$targetPath` and works fine. How will I achieve the same if `$targetPath` machine is in another domain?

i.e. sourceServer - Domain1, targetServer - Domain2

```
function evpcopy {
  begin {
    #Recommended options
    $switchNP = "/NP"    #No Progress - don't display percentage copied

    #Copy options
    $switchMIR = "/MIR"  #MIRror a directory tree (equivalent to /E plus /PURGE)
    $switchR = "/R:3"    #number of Retries on failed copies: default 1 million
    $switchW = "/W:1"    #Wait time between retries: default is 30 seconds

    $sourcePath = '\\sourceServer\d$\EVP'
    $targetPath = '\\targetServer\d$\EVP'

    #Log File Function
    $InputLogFile = 'D:\logs'

    if (!(Test-Path -Path $InputLogFile)) {
      Write-EventLog -LogName Application -source EvpScript -EventId 1234 -message "path $InputLogFile doesn't exist! `n"
    }

    $logfile = $InputLogFile + "\" + ((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')) + "_" + $sourcePath.Split('\')[-1].Replace(" ", "_") + ".txt" 
    $switchlogfile = "/TEE", "/LOG+:$logfile"
  }

  process {
    $run = robocopy.exe $sourcePath $targetPath $switchNP $switchR $switchW $switchMIR $switchlogfile |
           foreach { $ErrorActionPreference = "silentlycontinue" }
  }

  end {}
} #end robocopy function

evpcopy
```

Comment: Maybe using a `PSSession`? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849707.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map the target path to a drive and copy to that drive:

```
net use X: $targetPath /user:Domain2\username password
robocopy $sourcePath X: ...
net use X: /delete
```

The last line is to remove the drive after you're finished, so it doesn't keep lingering.

Comment: thanks Angsar. i used the powershell equivalent, which is new-psdrive and created Z: for the targetPath. now i am succesfully able to execute                      robocopy $sourcePath Z: ...

Comment: everything works fine when run from ISE. now my problem is that i need to create one scheduled task that runs 2 times a day. keeps robocopying $sourcePath to Z:. i ve used the same user account to set up the scheduled task as was used to creating the Z: drive. but while running on scheduled task, its giving me the error ..                                            2016/01/08 00:12:06 ERROR 3 (0x00000003) Creating Destination Directory Z:\
The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: Did you try with `net use`?

Comment: Under which account are you running the task?

Comment: thanks. this is now resolved. i used net use X:........    and robocopy and ..     and net use X: /delete                                                                                        in the same script. now it works

Comment: for some reason, if X: is already mapped earlier and we just call x: from the script while running from scheduled task, it says cannot find path x:                 hence the only option is to create X: in the script and delete it after the script has run

Comment: By default drives aren't removed automatically. You need to remove the drive yourself or use the switch `/persistent:no` to get it automatically removed at user logoff. I'd consider explicitly removing it the cleaner approach, though. Answer updated accordingly.